# UFW deny not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, ufw

The basic configuration is the following:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        xx.xxx.xxx
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Not using ipv6, verivied ipv4.  varnish and nginx logs show the ipv4 address that should be nuked from space.

ubuntu 16.04,

ufw 0.35
iptables v1.6.0

tried:

```
 ufw insert 1 deny from xx.xxx.xxx

ufw show raw: starts with
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       xx.xxx.xxx       0.0.0.0/0
```

In spite of this I can still pull a webpage down.  Its behind cloudflare and I get an nginx 404 (catch all 404) when going directly to the ip address (bypassing cloudflare completely.   Varnish on port 80 with nginx at 8080 on the backend, but the request should be completely ignored?

Comment: What does "nuked from space" mean?

Comment: slang reference to http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nuke-it-from-orbit

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with running the dev environment in a vm.  same exact os / setup deployed to a vps works perfectly.